# How access to original function in the class using proxy?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try do to monkey patch using Proxy to function in my class.

How can I access and invoke the original function?

```
class foo {
  x = 10;

  bar() {
    console.log({ x: this.x });
  }
}

foo.prototype.bar = new Proxy(foo.prototype.bar, {
  apply: function() {
    console.log("xxx");
    console.log({ that: this });

    this.bar();
  }
});

new foo().bar();
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xni9dd)

Comment: your `this` will be wrong since you are using an arrow function ... try to use a normal function and learn the difference between the two

Comment: I edit my question and use `function` keyword. still, how can I access to `foo.bar` original function?

Comment: "Unlike regular functions, arrow functions do not have their own this. The value of this inside an arrow function remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of this in the closest non-arrow parent function."

[Difference](https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256)

Comment: `foo.prototype._bar = foo.prototype.bar` then call `this._bar()`? - no that won't work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As seen on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply), the handler’s `apply` is called with the original function as an argument:

```js
class foo {
  x = 10;

  bar() {
    console.log({ x: this.x });
  }
}

foo.prototype.bar = new Proxy(foo.prototype.bar, {
  apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    console.log("xxx");
    Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList);
  },
});

new foo().bar();
```

(In general, the [`Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) functions can be used to delegate to whatever the proxy trap with the same name is wrapping.)

Note also that, as usual with proxies, you might not need them.

```js
class foo {
  x = 10;

  bar() {
    console.log({ x: this.x });
  }
}

const originalBar = foo.prototype.bar;

Object.assign(foo.prototype, {
  bar() {
    console.log("xxx");
    originalBar.call(this);
  },
});

new foo().bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, the `this` in your apply function is targeting its own scope. That means it references the (apply) function itself.

You can provide parameters to the apply function

```
apply: function(target, that, args) { ... }
```

The `target` is the bar function, the `that` is referencing the parent object and `args` ... you can guess :-)

```
class foo {
  x = 10;

  bar(value) {
    console.log('Class variable x: ', x);
    console.log('Method Parameter: ', value)
  }
}

foo.prototype["_bar"] = foo.prototype.bar;

foo.prototype.bar = new Proxy(foo.prototype.bar, {
  apply: function(target, that, args) {
    console.log("Target", target);
    console.log("THAT", that);
    console.log("args", args);
  }
});

new foo().bar('World');
```

If you would call `target.bar(args)` in your apply function, then you would get an endless loop.